# Linking external jars into final jar in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, static-linking

I'd like to pack two external libraries (OpenCSV & CommonCSV (Yes, later one I will recode everything to use only one)) into my main project - currently it throws

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter
```

I've tried putting them into my src folder - it increased the size of my jar but still no change.
Then I've added them in Properties->Libraries under the Compile, Processor & Run tabs. (I've added them as Jars)

Now all that still produces the same error - so what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by packing? You have an option to export project as .jar including libraries which are linked to the project so you end up with 1 jar file containing everything you need.

Comment: When I copy the .jar generated by `Clean & Build` to a folder without the lib folder present it does not function properly but throws the exception (when that class is used) - I want the files in the lib folder to be present in the final jar

Comment: Because you have to do export of the project to bundled jar. Not just by cleaning and building. At least that's the way I do it. Just rightclick on the project and chose something like export project. (that is in Eclipse, I don't remember how it is in netbeans)